# Rejection of papers

Tags: publications

I have already submitted a math paper to an outstanding journal. How much percent is probably my paper rejected after 7 months being under review?
During this time the date of status has been changed without changing the status "under review"?

Comment: Have you talked to your coauthors or supervisors about this?

Comment: Once my supervisor told me the average time is 6 month, but now is more than average

Comment: 7 > 6, quite right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really impossible to say. It could be anything, as you don't know the reason for what you perceive as a long delay. Depending on the subject, it may have taken a while to find suitable reviewers. The reviewers, once found, might be busy with other obligations. They may be very carefully reviewing your paper and constructing advice for its improvement. The editor may have been displeased with one of the reviews and sent it to someone else. Lots of possibilities.

Hearing back especially quickly, usually means rejection, not this sort of thing. You will know when you know and not sooner. You can ask the editor, of course, how things are going and may or may not get a reply.

Even knowing the average time that a paper is under review is little help as the variation is quite large. Patience is advised.